# Showing one marker at a time - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelgruber/M84T7/

When the codeAddress function is run more than once (when multiple inputs are run) the old markers are saved on the map. Why is this? Shouldn't the MyMap.marker be overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the MyMap.marker be overwritten?

Yes, but it is a reference to the marker not the marker itself.

To hide the marker:

```
 marker.setMap(null);
```

Before you overwrite it and lose the reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/zbZ8p/1/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is correct. I tried something like this before but this time I realized I need it to be:

MyMap.marker.setMap(null);
MyMap.marker = new... etc.