# Allow only one marker when doing geocode search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to allow a user to enter an address and it show their location on a map. I am using Google Maps API to do this following the [instructions provided](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

It works but I only want to allow one map marker at a time on the map. I attempted to follow the instructions found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575104/825757), however, it gave me an error: `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`

How do I allow only one marker at a time while keeping the same behavior in the example provided by Google?

Here is the code the combines Google's code with the SO Answer I link to:

```
var marker;

function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        //if marker already was created change positon
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        //create a marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
    }
}

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
             /* ORIGINAL GOOGLE CODE COMMENTED OUT TO TRY AND PREVENT MULTIPLE MARKERS
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });*/
          //CODE ADDED IN PLACE OF GOOGLE CODE THAT REFERENCES FUNCTION ABOVE
              placeMarker(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
          alert('We could not locate your location for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` variable is local to the initMap function.  You have two options for fixing the issue:

1. make it global
2. pass it in to the placeMarker function

[#1 proof of concept fiddle (make the `map` variable global)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lfzvyo9k/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;
var map;  // global map variable

function placeMarker(location) {
  if (marker && marker.setPosition) {
    //if marker already was created change positon
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    //create a marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
  }
}

function initMap() {
  // no "var" here, initialize the global map variable
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 39.8282,
      lng: -98.5795
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      placeMarker(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert('We could not locate your location for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="text" id="address" value="Boston, MA" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

[#2 proof of concept fiddle (pass the `map` variable into the `placeMarker` function)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lfzvyo9k/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;

function placeMarker(location, map) {
  if (marker && marker.setPosition) {
    //if marker already was created change positon
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    //create a marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
  }
}

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 39.8282,
      lng: -98.5795
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      placeMarker(results[0].geometry.location, resultsMap);
    } else {
      alert('We could not locate your location for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="text" id="address" value="Boston, MA" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
<div id="map"></div>
```